# How to zip vectors using template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am practicing on template meta-programming and wanted to implement a simple trivial meta-function. I wonder how one can implement zip functionality on custom vectors. What I have in my mind is as follows:

Here is how the zip operation for this custom vector look like:

Inputs:

```
Vector<1, 2, 3>
Vector<2, 3, 4>
Vector<3, 4, 5>
```

Output:

```
Vector<6, 24, 60>
```

I believe my `Vector` class should be declared like:

```
template<int... vals>
struct Vector;
```

zip meta-function should have the signature:

```
template<typename... Vectors>
struct zip
{
    ///
}
```

I cannot figure out how to multiply values in the input vectors that happen to be in the same index via template meta-programming?

Comment: I think you use the term `zip` here, while you want something else. From Inputs and Outputs, it seems like you want `o[0] = i0[0] * i1[0] * i2[0]` etc. While the term zip usually refers to yielding a `Vector<int[3]>` or similar (`{ {1,2,3} , {2,3,4}, {3,4,5} }`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can partially specialise `zip` in order to expose the template parameters of the `Vector`s you pass.

```
template<typename...>
struct zip;

template<int... Us, int... Vs, typename... Tail>
struct zip<Vector<Us...>, Vector<Vs...>, Tail...> {
    using type = typename zip<Vector<(Us * Vs)...>, Tail...>::type;
};

template<typename T>
struct zip<T> {
    using type = T;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<zip<Vector<2, 4, 6>, 
                               Vector<1, 2, 3>, 
                               Vector<3, 6, 9>>::type, 
                               /* == */ Vector<6, 48, 162>>::value);
```

Comment: missing `typename` after that it is ok: https://godbolt.org/z/hPoand6vY

Comment: is this fold expression?

Comment: No before dependent type:`using type = typename zip....::type`

Comment: @MarekR Thanks. GCC's trunk compiles the code with C++20, so I didn't think anything of it. Edited the answer.

Comment: C++20 has new rule which discards `typedef` in such scenario. Clang didn't implemented that feature yet so it is better to provide `typename` anyway even with C++20.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
template<int... vals>
struct Vector;

template<typename...Ts>
struct zip;

template<int...vals>
struct zip<Vector<vals...>>
{
    using type = Vector<vals...>;
};

template<int...Avals, int...Bvals, typename...Ts>
struct zip<Vector<Avals...>, Vector<Bvals...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename zip<Vector<(Avals*Bvals)...>, Ts...>::type;
};

template<typename...Ts>
using zip_t = typename zip<Ts...>::type;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8KjMj69Y6

Answer (score 0):

By taking the heads off and zipping those:-
(Test results: https://godbolt.org/z/634d7WhMn )

```cpp
    template <int...Ts>
    struct Vector
        {
        using type = Vector <Ts...>;
        };
        
    struct multiply
        {
        template <int v1, int v2>
        struct op
            {
            static const int value = v1*v2;
            };
        };
        
    template <int, class ...>
    struct con;
    template <int H, int ...Ts>
    struct con <H, Vector<Ts...>>:
        Vector <H, Ts...>
        {};
    
    template <class...>
    struct zip;
    template <class OP, int H1, int H2> 
    struct zip <OP, Vector <H1>, Vector <H2>>:
        Vector< OP::template op<H1,H2>::value>
        {};
    template <class OP, int H1, int ...T1s, int H2, int ...T2s> 
    struct zip <OP, Vector <H1, T1s...>, Vector <H2, T2s...>>:
        con <
            OP::template op<H1,H2>::value, 
            typename zip <OP, Vector <T1s...>, Vector <T2s...>>::type
            >
        {};
    
    template <template <class...> class T_FN, class TV>
    struct curryr
        {
        template <class ... T>
        struct op:
            T_FN<TV, T ...>
            {};
         };
         
    template <class...Ts> 
    struct foldl;
    template <class OP_WRAP, class T0, class T>
    struct foldl <OP_WRAP, T0, T>:
        OP_WRAP::template op <T0, T>
        {};
    template <class OP_WRAP, class T0, class T1, class...Ts>
    struct foldl <OP_WRAP, T0, T1, Ts...>:
        foldl
            <
            OP_WRAP, 
            typename OP_WRAP::template op <T0, T1>::type,
            Ts...
            >
        {};
    template <class OP_WRAP, class T0>
    struct foldl <OP_WRAP, T0>:
        T0
        {};
    
    using type = typename foldl<curryr<zip, multiply>, Vector<1,2,3>, Vector<4,5,6>, Vector<7,8,9>>::type;
```